# In what range are HTML5 Geolocation longitudes provided?

Tags: html

I live in the western hemisphere. If I were to perform an HTML5 geolocation request right now, I would get:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (x) {
    console.log(x);
});

Position {coords: Coordinates, timestamp: 1545145691417}
    coords: Coordinates
        accuracy: 29
        altitude: null
        altitudeAccuracy: null
        heading: null
        latitude: 40.xxx
        longitude: -80.xxx
        speed: null
    __proto__: Coordinates
    timestamp: 1545145691417
```

With a longitude being -80, which implies the longitude ranges between [-180, 180]. The vast majority of my API consumers report locations in this range. However, from a Samsung Galaxy J3 running Android 7, I get this:

```
latitude    Decimal('40.xxx')
longitude   Decimal('190.xxx')
```

with a longitude greater than 180, which means the longitudes coming from that device ranges from [0, 360], and [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) does not mention the longitude's range. Why is this only happening on the J3?